# How can I get icons to stay in background and swapped text to display correct on CSS/jQuery hover/mouseenter?

Tags: jquery, css

I have build the below CSS and jQuery, that display some additional info on hover/mouseenter, however I have dificulties getting the font awsome icons on the siblings to hide when I hover over one of the DIV, and the text that I swap the icons with on mouseenter is "jumping" and I cannot get it to display correct (i.e. the `<br>` is very large)

How can I:

1. Get the icons on siblings to stay in the back on mouseenter?
2. How do I get the text swapped to "normalize" so that it will display as it should (i.e the `<br>` to break line normally and not "jumping")?

**My code :**

```js
$("#SystemInfodiv1").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#SystemInfodiv1").removeClass("pulse red");
  $("#SystemInfoText1").html("<b>Last Database Backup:</b><br>20-05-2021 01:16:24");
});
$("#SystemInfodiv1").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#SystemInfoText1").html("<i class='fas fa-database'></i>");
});

$("#SystemInfodiv2").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#SystemInfodiv2").even().removeClass("pulse red");
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html("<b>Database Size:</b><br>3.87 GB of 6.13 GB used storage");
});
$("#SystemInfodiv2").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#SystemInfoText2").html("<i class='far fa-hdd'></i>");
});

$("#SystemInfodiv3").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#SystemInfodiv3").even().removeClass("pulse red");
  $("#SystemInfoText3").html("<b>Last sync with AD:</b><br>21-05-2021 07:00:04");
});
$("#SystemInfodiv3").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#SystemInfoText3").html("<i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>");
});
```

```css
#SystemInfoTable {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 190px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
}

.SystemInfodiv {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition-property: width height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
}

.SystemInfodiv:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}

.SystemInfodiv:hover {
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: scale(4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.SystemInfoText {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.SystemInfoText:hover {
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 15;
  font-size: 4px;
}

.pulse.red {
  background: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  animation: pulse-red 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse-red {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7fa152c719.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table id="SystemInfoTable">
  <tr style="border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF;">
    <td valign="bottom">
      <div id="SystemInfodiv1" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText1" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-database"></i></span></div>
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
      <div id="SystemInfodiv2" class="SystemInfodiv bg-warning"><span id="SystemInfoText2" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="far fa-hdd"></i></span></div>
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
      <div id="SystemInfodiv3" class="SystemInfodiv bg-danger pulse red"><span id="SystemInfoText3" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using a `table` to achieve this layout that would simplify the markup.

HTML

```
<div id="SystemInfoTable">
    <div id="SystemInfodiv1" class="SystemInfodiv bg-success"><span id="SystemInfoText1" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
    <div id="SystemInfodiv2" class="SystemInfodiv bg-warning"><span id="SystemInfoText2" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="far fa-hdd" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
    <div id="SystemInfodiv3" class="SystemInfodiv bg-danger"><span id="SystemInfoText3" class="SystemInfoText"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#SystemInfoTable {
    display: flex;
}
```

CSS
`position: relative;` should keep the current/hover element over the other icons. `z-index` requires `position` to work, without it does nothing. Be careful not to over use `position` and `z-index`, it can get you into a lot of mess if you do.

```
.SystemInfodiv {
    position: relative;
}
```

---

You're using `transition-property: all;` and that will transition every property, try setting it to specific properties so you only transition what you need, this may help your jumpy hover styles.

Also consider maybe having a child element with the info you need and style that element, add/edit it's content and hide and show the child element on hover.

Comment: the change from table to div fixed the first issue with the icons ;-) .. I have removed `transition-property: all;` and also tried to change the property but that does not help .. I think I will try to work on hide/show a child element as you suggest, it sounds like a good way to go .. I will get back when I have tried that solution :-)

Comment: Hi @dylanjameswagner .. I have tried to create an animation in jQuery to swap between 2 DIV´s, but it is not given me the result I wish to, I have only been able to make it with fadeIn/fadeOut and it does not give me the effect I need, and I have not been able to find exables or documentation on how I can make the Animation between the 2 DIV´s .. do you have an example perhaps? :-)

Comment: @StigKølbæk I don't understand what you are asking for, "swap between 2 divs", I am wondering if you can do your hide/show with CSS instead of JS. From there you can use CSS transitions etc.

Comment: I fully understand why, you do not, because I totally misunderstood what you meant .. but I have fixed it now, and it is working  :-) .. only one issue left, but I will post that in another question :-) .. you can see the result here (the issue is that mouseleave also sets a mouseenter which I do not understand why is) .. https://jsfiddle.net/skolbaek/5czb4qLy/1/